# Function does not store all the output

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I have the following list,

```
p=[list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e'])]
```

I would like to make the subset of each element (of size 2) and list them, this would give the output as follow:

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')],[('d', 'e')]]
```

To achieve this I wrote the following function,

```
def x(m,n):
    for i in x:
        z=list(itertools.combinations(i, n))
    return(z)
```

yet when I apply ie `z(m,2)` I only get the last element:

```
[('d', 'e')]
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `for i in x` when `x` is the function name? That does not seem correct...

Comment: You are overwriting `z` on each iteration

Comment: The code as such cannot be run, please fix it, and do `z.append(list(itertools.combinations(i, n)))` where `z` is a list

Comment: That doesn't look like a list. That looks like you have a NumPy array and you're pretending it's a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are setting z each time instead of appending it:

```py
def x(m,n):
    z = []
    for i in m:
        z.append(list(itertools.combinations(i, n)))
    return(z)
```

yileds:

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')], [('d', 'e')]]
```